# Android Studio: Application crashes at start

Tags: java, android, exception, crash, logcat

my application crashes at start and I have no idea why. I'm testing it on a real device (Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300). Here is the exception:

[image]

**EDIT:**

So, that's what I've added to onCreate():

```
walking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            travel_mode = "walking";
            walking.setImageResource(R.drawable.walking_sel);
            biking.setImageResource(R.drawable.regular_biking);
            driving.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_icon);
            transit.setImageResource(R.drawable.transit_icon);
        }
        });

    biking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            travel_mode = "biking";
            walking.setImageResource(R.drawable.walking);
            biking.setImageResource(R.drawable.regular_biking_sel);
            driving.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_icon);
            transit.setImageResource(R.drawable.transit_icon);
        }
    });
```

Before I've added this piece of code, everything worked correctly.

And here is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lukssoftware.kaart" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="***" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="lukssoftware.kaart.kaart_welcome"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="kaart" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Code is matter a lot....  my friend  ...

Comment: please post your code and explain what were you trying to do

Comment: Okay, problem is solved. I defined walking and biking outside of onCreate(). The problem is now solved! :) Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post more code and there is nothing to do with manifest here post layout xml and activity code where you have defined walking and biking findViews(). 
Just check it out that you have defined findViewsById of both walking and biking before you are calling setOnClickListener method.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application still compile successfully after deleting the two modules?

If it doesn't compile, look for the lines in your classes or xml files which have yellow or red exclamation marks. That should alert you to where the problem is coming from.

You should also take a good look at line 64 in your *welcome.java class.